# Take data from clicked ListView

Tags: c#, xaml

I have XAML file like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="UISkripsi3.Sidebar"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:UISkripsi3="clr-namespace:UISkripsi3"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UISkripsi3">
<UserControl.Template>

        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UISkripsi3:Sidebar}">
            <DataTemplate x:Key="StatusAndOther" DataType="{x:Type local:NewsFeedResources}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
                                <Image x:Name="ProfilePicture" Source="{Binding Path=ProfilePict}" Stretch="Fill" Width="80" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UserName}" Style="{StaticResource UserNameStyle}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Message}" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>                                      
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image x:Name="Icon" Source="{Binding Path=icon}" Width="10" Height="10"></Image>
                                        <TextBlock Text=" via " Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=attribution}" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Button x:Name="LikeButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="like" IsEnabled="{Binding canLike}" ToolTip="Like" Click="LikeButtonClick">
                                          <Button.Style>
                                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource LikeButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button">
                                              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                              <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding hasLiked}" Value="True">
                                                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                              </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                          </Button.Style>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button x:Name="RemoveLikeButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="remove like" IsEnabled="{Binding hasLiked}" ToolTip="Remove Like">
                                          <Button.Style>
                                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource RemoveLikeButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button">
                                              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                              <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding hasLiked}" Value="False">
                                                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                              </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                          </Button.Style>
                                        </Button>
                                    </StackPanel>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>                               
                            </StackPanel>   
                    </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ListView Name="NewsFeedList" Width="700" Height="500" Margin="10"  
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Sidebar.newsFeedResourcesCoba2}}" 
                                  Background="Black" 
                                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}" Focusable="False">                            
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>                
                    </Grid>                 
                </DataTemplate>
        </ControlTemplate>

</UserControlTemplate>

</UserControl>
```

Then, I have class like this

```
public class NewsFeedResources : UserControl

{       

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string IdPost { get; set; }
        public byte[] ProfilePict { get; set; }
        public string DestinationName { get; set; }
        public string to { get; set; }
        public byte[] UploadedPict { get; set; }
        public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string nameWallPost { get; set; }
        public string captionWallPost { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public byte[] icon { get; set; }
        public string attribution { get; set; }
        public bool canLike { get; set; }
        public bool hasLiked { get; set; }  

}
```

Lets add some data

```
public static ObservableCollection < NewsFeedResources > _newsfeedcoba2 = new ObservableCollection < NewsFeedResources >();

public static ObservableCollection < NewsFeedResources > newsFeedResourcesCoba2
        { get { return _newsfeedcoba2; } }

_newsfeedcoba2.Add(new NewsFeedResources 

{ 

UserName = "abc", Id = "123", Message = "Hello World", IdPost = "12345-12345", ProfilePict = data, DestinationName = "Boulevard", to = "John", UploadedPict = data2, Attachment = data2, Description = "Bored", type = tipeStatus, nameWallPost = nameWallPost, captionWallPost = caption, link = linknya, icon = data3, attribution = attributenya, canLike = blumLike, hasLiked = sdhLike

}
);
```

Code above is just some part of my program and it works fine. I want to ask about the ListView (x:name="NewsFeedList"). I want that if I click the LikeButton, a messagebox appeared and display the IdPost. I don't know how to pass the value from xaml to xaml.cs. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void LikeButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
    Button btn = (Button)sender; 
    NewsFeedResources obj = btn.DataContext as NewsFeedResources;  
    if(null != obj){ 
         MessageBox.Show(obj.IdPost);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works.. Now, I have a new question. I have edited my previous question.

Comment: @Wandy Wujayanto: Do not change your question after persons have answered. If this answer helped, acccept it and make a new question for your new request. This is how SO works. You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark below of the points-display (if it helped you). You can revert back to your previous version of the question by clicking on the link that shows the time of editing your post.

Comment: @ HCL : Thanks for the advice. I am new to SO, thanks a lot. I have clicked the link you said.